# How can I get my sequence nextval using QueryDSL?

Tags: java, querydsl

I was digging around to find a solution to this problem using Oracle and the only thing I was able to find so far was the method ***nextval*** from ***com.mysema.query.sql.SQLExpression***, but yet I'm not quite sure how to use it and didn't find anything at all even in the documentation.

Is there someone who had to use it and also have it figured out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just call

```
SQLExpressions.nextval("sequence name")
```

to get an expression of Long type

If you need another type you call e.g.

```
SQLExpressions.nextval(Integer.class, "sequence name")
```

Comment: Is it called using queries like JPAQuery, SQLQuery, JPASQLQuery, etc. or is it called in a different manner? I've tried using those three queries so far and couldn't make this work at all.

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace. SQLQuery and JPASQLQuery should work. JPAQuery is for JPA queries (ORM queries).

Comment: From-less queries are now allowed also on the JPA side, they work already for SQLQuery https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues/467